# I've 103775 posts on my WordPress site. the following queries constantly overloading my MySQL database server. how can I permanently fix it?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have 103775 posts on my WordPress site and the following queries constantly overloading my MySQL database server. How can I permanently fix it?

First one:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_posts 
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta 
      ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 
      AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'post_views_count') 
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
      AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC 
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Second:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
     ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
  WHERE 1=1 
    AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (127,188,190)) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4
```

Third:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
  FROM wp_posts 
  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships 
     ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
  WHERE 1=1 
    AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (127,188,190)) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 4
```

What does these queries do & how can I avoid generating these queries from overloading my MySQL database server?

Comment: the second and third are the same?

Answer (score 0):

i would start by verifying all fields used in where statements are indexed (chich should be the case).
There is also performance problems with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
as you can see here :
[wordpress generating slow mysql queries - is it index problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448247/wordpress-generating-slow-mysql-queries-is-it-index-problem)
and here
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10964

Then i would check if mysql_cache is enabled and add a cache plugin.

Comment: there isn't much that indexing can do in this case, since it is selecting rows based on one table but ordering them based on a different table.  I'm sure the obvious indexes are there.

Comment: I've this config in my php & db server.  

https://downloads.intercomcdn.com/i/o/477189802/b3ae92c557c59274ee203236/image.png?expires=1646801103&signature=0d003b42e1022b404c9936e0aa8aa1184e7a4107e7964adc7409648be396baff

Can you please tell me if everything is ok & correct or not?

Comment: the link is dead